# how to modify the array based on extension

Tags: javascript

I want to modify an `array` of `object` to split its `sub-array` 'files' into two categories based on the file extension.

- `img[]` (List of files with the ending .jpg)
- `pdf[]` (List of files with the ending .pdf)

```js
var test = [ 
  {
  name: 'ter3',
  files: ['dsf.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}, {
   name: 'test2',
  files: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}
]

test.filter(item => {
   item.files.filter(file => {
       if(file.indexOf('jpg') !== -1) {
         console.log(file)
       }

    })
})

console.log(test)
```

I want to modified above array into this.

```
var test = [ 
  {
  name: 'ter3',
  files: ['dsf.jpg', 'test.pdf', 'lolwa.jpg'],
   img: ['dsf.jpg', 'lolwa.jpg'],
   pdf: ['test.pdf']
}, {
   name: 'test2',
  files: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg', 're.pdf'],
  img: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg'],
  pdf: ['re.pdf']
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with `array.map()` like in the following snippet:

```js
var test = [ 
  {
  name: 'ter3',
  files: ['dsf.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}, {
   name: 'test2',
  files: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}
]

test.map(item => { //Map the array
  item.img = [] //Initialize the img and pdf arrays
  item.pdf = []
  
  item.files.forEach(file => { //Add to the img and pdf array accordingly
    if(file.endsWith('.jpg')) {
      item.img.push(file)
    } else if (file.endsWith('.pdf')) {
      item.pdf.push(file)
    }
  })
    
   return item
})

console.log(test)
```

Comment: This would fail for files named like `something.jpg.pdf` or even `myjpg.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

This should work using regular expressions. It uses the modifier `i` (case insensitivity) to also match files ending with `.JPG` or `.PDF`.

```js
var test = [{
  name: 'ter3',
  files: ['dsf.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}, {
  name: 'test2',
  files: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}];

test.forEach(obj => {
  obj.img = obj.files.filter(file => /\.jpg$/i.test(file));
  obj.pdf = obj.files.filter(file => /\.pdf$/i.test(file));
});

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
var test = [ 
  {
  name: 'ter3',
  files: ['dsf.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}, {
   name: 'test2',
  files: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}
];

test.forEach(obj => {
  obj.files.forEach(file => {
    const fileExtension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    obj[fileExtension] = obj[fileExtension] || [];
    obj[fileExtension].push(file);
  });
});

console.log(test);
```

This would create keys, depending on the file extension and is not limited to hardcoded values such as `jpg` or `png`. It should also account for some edge cases like files name weirdly like `file.pdf.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It also accounts for jpg and pdf being the last string. So something like ijpg.pdf will match as pdf, not jpg

```
var test = [ 
  {
  name: 'ter3',
  files: ['dsf.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}, {
   name: 'test2',
  files: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}
]

test = test.map(item=>{
  item['img'] = item.files.filter(file=>{
    return /\.jpg$/.test(file)
  });
item['pdf'] = item.files.filter(file=>{
    return /\.pdf$/.test(file)
  });

  return item;
});

console.log(test)
```

https://jsbin.com/lanukelugu/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "dictionary" of rules for each file extension like so:

```js
var test = [
  {
    name: "ter3",
    files: ["dsf.jpg", "test.jpg", "lolwa.pdf"]
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    files: ["te.jpg", "fgfd.jpg", "lolwa.pdf"]
  }
];

const rules = {
  jpg: "img",
  pdf: "pdf"
};

test.forEach(obj => {
  obj.files.forEach(file => {
    const extension = rules[file.substr(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)];
    obj[extension] != undefined
      ? obj[extension].push(file)
      : (obj[extension] = [file]);
  });
});
console.log(test);
```

Comment: This would fail for files named with dots - `filename.image.img`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Using_test()):

```js
var test = [ 
  {
  name: 'ter3',
  files: ['dsf.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}, {
   name: 'test2',
  files: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}
];

const arr = test.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  img: obj.files.filter(f => /\.jpg$/.test(f)),
  pdf: obj.files.filter(f => /\.pdf$/.test(f))
}));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// The array to process.
var input = [ 
  {
  name: 'ter3',
  files: ['dsf.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}, {
   name: 'test2',
  files: ['te.jpg', 'fgfd.jpg', 'lolwa.pdf']
}
],
// An array with file type. This makes it easy to add new types.
fileTypes = [
  {
    id: 'pdf',
    predicate: /.pdf$/i
  },
  {
    id: 'img',
    predicate: /.(jpg|bmp)$/i
  }
];

// Create a new array where each entry of the input array is enriched with
// a property per file type listing the files that match that file type.
var output = input.map(entry => {
  // Create a copy of the current object so the original object
  // is not modified.
  const modifiedEntry = {...entry};
  
  // Iterate over all the file types. For each entry, add a property with the
  // name equal to the ID and filter the files based on the predicate.
  fileTypes.forEach(fileType => {
    modifiedEntry[fileType.id] = entry.files.filter(item => fileType.predicate.test(item))
  });
  
  // Return the modified entry.
  return modifiedEntry;
});
  
// Log the input, this should be unchanged from when we started.  
console.log('--[ input ]--');
console.log(input);
// Log the output.  
console.log('--[ output ]--');
console.log(output);
```